# MongoDB - Index usage for different queries with the same results

Tags: mongodb, indexing, compound-index

I have 2 queries with the same result as below:

```
Query 1: {
    $or: [
        {
            field_1: "A",
        },
        {
            field_2: "B",
        },
    ],
    field_3: "C",
},

Query 2: {
    $or: [
        {
            field_1: "A",
            field_3: "C",
        },
        {
            field_2: "B",
            field_3: "C",
        },
    ],
}
```

I'm having 2 compound indices: `field_3_field_1` and `field_3_field_2`.

Explaining query executions of both queries shows that:

- Query 1 ran faster (3 times) with seeks equal to 1, with much higher `totalKeysExamined` and `totalDocsExamined` (these two are the same) and used 1 of above indices.
- Query 2 ran slower with much higher seeks (32), with much lower `totalKeysExamined` and `totalDocsExamined`, both indices were used.

Can anyone explain this behaviour and what would be the recommended way to query this? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please try using an _explicit_ `$and` operator for the _first_ query and see what the results are.

Comment: Hi @prasad_, running explain on the first query has indeed resulted in an explicit `$and` parsed query.

Comment: You may want to take a look at this note: [$or clause and Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/operator/query/or/#behaviors).